# Elliptic Curves over $F_{p^2}$

Tags: finite-fields, elliptic-curves

For a finite field $F_{p^2}$, polynomial elements appear. For example, $F_{2^2}=\{0,1,x,x+1\}$.

Now when defining an Elliptic Curve $E:y^2=x^3+Ax+B$ over a field of the form $F_{p^2}$.

Does this mean that $A$ and $B$ can be polynomials??

Comment: Strictly speaking, $A$ and $B$ are elements of the field $F_{2^2}$ that we are realizing as a quotient $F_2[t] / \langle p(t) \rangle$ of the polynomial ring $F_2[t]$ by the (maximal) ideal generated by a particular irreducible polynomial (in this case our only choice is $p(t) = t^2 + t + 1$). Alternatively, we can regard elements of the field as elements generated over $F_2$ by $\alpha$ and subject to the relation $\alpha^2 + \alpha + 1 = 0$. In either case, it's misleading to use the coordinate $x$ appearing in the definition of the elliptic curve for the indeterminate/adjoined element.

Comment: So if $E:y^2=x^3+Ax+B$ over $F_{2^2}=\{0,1,α,α+1\}$ then,

$y^2=x^3+αx+α+1$ is an elliptic curve defined over $F_{2^2}$??

And also, what is '$α$'. Is it a constant? I understand that it's an indetermined element, but are there ways to determine it?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. If we think of $F_{2^2}$ as the quotient $F_2[t] / \langle t^2 + t + 1\rangle$, then $\alpha$ is just the image $t + \langle t^2 + t + 1 \rangle$ of $t$ under the quotient map $F_2[t] \to F_2[t] / \langle t^2 + t + 1\rangle$.

Comment: Ok great, is it correct to consider $A,\; B$ as elements of the quotient ring ?

Comment: Yes, or more to the point, $A, B$ are elements of the field. By the way, note that because our underlying field $F_{2^2}$ has characteristic $2$, /not/ all elliptic curves over that field can be written in the usual reduced form $y^2 = x^3 + A x + B$ after applying a suitable affine transformation. The best we can do in our case is (I think) $y^2 + A x y + B y = x^3 + C x^2 + D x + E$.

Comment: Yup, $\alpha\in F_4$ should be treated as a constant. When studying field extension you will similarly see $\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt2]$ constructed as $\Bbb{Q}[t]/\langle t^2-2\rangle$. You can try to thing of the coset $\beta=t+\langle t^2-2\rangle$ as an indeterminate, but it is surely more convenient to think of $\beta$ as $\sqrt2$. Observe that if we didn't have the idea of thinking of $\sqrt2$ as a real number $1.4142\ldots$ we would need to construct it first. Construct it exactly as such a coset to be more precise!

Comment: (cont'd) For calculations it is surely better to just stick to thinking that $\beta=\sqrt2$ is just a constant that satisfies the simplification rule $\beta^2=2$. (in comparison to substituting $1.4142\cdots$ in its place everywhere). Same thing with your $\alpha\in F_4$. It is just a constant that follows the rule $\alpha^2=\alpha+1$. It differs from $\sqrt2=1.4142\cdots$ dualism in the sense that this time we have no viable alternatives. We **have to** think of $\alpha$ as a constant that follows that rule. You'll get used to thinking about it this way soon enough!

Comment: You should look at elliptic curves over complex numbers, $a+ib$ being after all a polynomial in $i = \sqrt{-1}$.

Comment: Hmm, ok... so is what I am saying here wrong?: 
$y^2=x^3-3x+4=x^3+2x+4$ is an elliptic curve defined over $F_{5^2}$

Comment: I'm sure that this is ok since $F_p$ is contained in $F_{p^2}$.... I think for my work I will avoid using the 'polynomial' elements of $F_{p^2}$ as coefficients for simplicity.